# C# Simple Chat application with Remoting: Client form not updating

Tags: c#, chat, remoting

I'm trying to create a simple chat application using remoting in C# (Visual Studio).
My problem is that, the client sends a connect request to the server with the port, the server receives this request, registers the client in a dictionary with the port and then sends back a greet message to the client (just to test). I can print the message from the server in the clients console, but the form doesnt update.

Here's the code:

In the shared library of the client and the server i have two interfaces, one for the services of the server:

```
namespace ChatApplication
{
    public interface IServerServices
    {
        void sendMessage(string client, string msg);

        void register(string client, int port);

    }
}
```

And another for the services of a client:

```
namespace ChatApplication
{
    public interface IClientServices
    {
        void receiveMsg(string s);
    }
}
```

In the server i have:

```
namespace ChatApplication
{
    public class ChatServer
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(8086);
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
                typeof(ServerServices),
                "RemoteObject",
                WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);        
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And the class that implements the Server services:

```
namespace ChatApplication
{
    public class ServerServices : MarshalByRefObject, IServerServices
    {
        private Dictionary<string, IClientServices> clients =
            new Dictionary<string, IClientServices>();

        public void register(string client, int port)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Registered client: " + client + " on port: " + port);
        IClientServices cli = (IClientServices )Activator.GetObject(
            typeof(IClientServices),
            "tcp://localhost:" + port + "/RemoteClient");

        clients.Add(client, cli);
        cli.receiveMsg("Hello client " + client); //Just to test the form on the client
    }

}
```

}

In the client I have the main class of the client:

```
namespace ChatApplication
{
    static class ChatClient
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

The class that implements the services of the client:

```
namespace ChatApplication
{
    public class ClientServices : MarshalByRefObject, IClientServices 
    {

        public static Form1 myForm;

        public ClientServices ()
        {
        }

        public void receiveMsg(string s)
        {
            myForm.addMsg(s);
        }

    }
}
```

And finally the form application of the client:

```
namespace ChatApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        TcpChannel newch;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void addMsg(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("received msg " + s);
            session.Text += s + "\r\n";
        }

        public void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int port = Int32.Parse(portText.Text);
            newch = new TcpChannel(port);
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(newch, false);
            ClientServices.myForm = this;
            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
                typeof(ClientServices),
                "RemoteClient",
                WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);

            IServerServices serverInstance = (IServerServices)Activator.GetObject(
            typeof(IServerServices),
            "tcp://localhost:8086/RemoteObject");

            serverInstance.register(nickname.Text, port);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I see in the client's console the text "Hello client " + ...
But the element session of the client's form does not update and the client crashes. The class that implements the client's services has the field myForm has static because i don't know other way to publish a remote object that has fields, so I did in that way and i guess it works, it's just that the form does not update. What am i doing wrong?

Sorry for all the code but i guess this way you can see whats going on here.

Comment: How does it crash? Any meaningful errormesages? Like something mentionning cross-thread operations?

Comment: The client just freezes but if i put a breakpoint in this line: serverInstance.register(nickname.Text, porto); i get an SocketException: no connection was made because the target denied it. (i translated the message to english)

Comment: Any particular reason to use Remoting? It's a little outdated, so many beter options around now.

Comment: Homework for college

Comment: Hmmm... A very old college?

Comment: Yeah I guess. I don't know what to tell you. It's a course in Distributed Systems of my minor. Can you help me at all or are we going on with this conversation?

Comment: No, my knowledge of Remoting has faded away...

Comment: @riotvan Could you post the full exception message please? Does it mention ::1:8086 at the end?

Answer (score 0):

A wild stab in the dark: this may be a concurrency problem. Try serialising access to the client UI so you don't get overlapped access. For that matter, are you marshalling onto the UI thread when you access the UI? A cursory check of your UI code makes me think this isn't the problem (Console.WriteLine should do that for you) but until you post that error message no one can be very helpful.